# What is wrong with my code, reversing the order of an array?

Tags: arrays, logic, autohotkey

This is what I wrote, the array that is returned is ["5","4","3","4","5"] and I don't understand why?  Please enlighten me :)

```
Name:=["1","2","3","4","5"]
object:=[]
object:=Name
n:=0

while(n<NumGet(&object + 4*A_PtrSize)){

    s:=NumGet(&object + 4*A_PtrSize)-n
    ++n
    Name[n]:=object[s]
}
```

As always, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying `Name` into `object` which makes them the same array, so when you modify `Name`, you are overwriting the entries in `object` you need later. You need to make a copy of `Name`, not just assign it to `object`.

```
object := Name.Clone()
```